# Setting up separate ASP.NET app with DotNetNuke

Tags: web-config, dotnetnuke

I've got DotNetNuke (v5.1.4 Community Edition) setup on a Windows Server 2008 64-bit system (using SQL Server 2008 64-bit for the backend database), and I want to reference a separate ASP.NET application from it.  I plan to display the ASP.NET application via an IFrame module on the DNN site.  I'd like the ASP.NET application to recognize the user that is currently logged into the DNN site.  I'm trying to do this by creating a web application (in IIS) under the DNN web site on the web server.  That is, the ASP.NET web application is a child of the DNN web site (we're using IIS7).

When I do this and then navigate to the ASP.NET site I get this error message:

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'DotNetNuke.HttpModules' or one of its
>   dependencies."

Based on [this article](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/ForumsDotNetNuke/tabid/795/forumid/108/threadid/15438/scope/posts/Default.aspx).  I added the < clear / > tag to the httpModules section of the ASP.NET applications web.config.

Now I'm getting this error message:

> "Could not load file or assembly
>   'DotNetNuke' or one of its
>   dependencies"

Also, the debugging information mentions something about DotNetNuke.UI.WebControls.CaptchaHandler, but I don't think that's the source of the problem.  That is, it's just a coincidence that the CaptchaHandler is the first item in the httpHandlers section.

I tried adding the < clear / > tag to the httpHandlers section, but get this error message:

> "No http handler was found for request
>   type 'GET'"

Any ideas on what might be going on and how to fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can modify the root dnn web.config and add **`<location inheritInChildApplications="false">`** around the **`<system.webServer>`** and **`<system.web>`** tags.

The end result will be something along these lines...

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
  <system.webServer>

  ...

  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>

  ...

  </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you may have missed a step from that post - what you need to do is in the application that is sitting 'below' dnn make sure that you remove the http modules in its web.config. It doesnt sound like you have done that.