# DotNetNuke module development errors after upgrading to VS 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dotnetnuke

I have been working on building a DNN module in VS 2010 under DNN 7.0.3.  My module has a few controls, a web service, and some jQuery/Ajax calls to the web service.  I am working in Windows 7 with IIS 7.  Everything was fine until I upgraded to VS 2012. After that, I was getting 500 errors for all the files I am loading into my control, i.e. javascript files, css files, and even images (never saw a 500 error on an image before!).  I tried rolling back my project to before I loaded it into VS 2012, but that didn't help.  I found this article: [Setting up separate ASP.NET app with DotNetNuke](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2088400/setting-up-separate-asp-net-app-with-dotnetnuke) 
and implemented the suggestion in answer 2 (adding location... to the web config file).  That fixed most of the problems, but I am still getting 500 errors for 2 HttpHandlers I built (which just spit out some javascript) and for any calls to my web service.  The error I am getting now is:

Parser Error. An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request.   Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

It kind of looks like it can't find the codebehind for these files.  That makes some sense, since that was basically the problem it was having with all the files before I added the  tag to the web.config.

I tried a clean install of DNN 7.0.6 and just installed my module from the package that was created earlier, but still the same errors.  Since I haven't made any change to my code since it was last working, I am pretty sure the problem has something to do with changes the VS 2012 install made to my machine but I have no idea what.  Please help!!!

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

Check to see if you have a VIRTUAL DIRECTORY or Application on the DesktopModules folder, or on the Module's folder in there, sometimes that happens in VS.

Also make sure there is NOT a web.config file in the MODULE folder.

Comment: We had this same issue, looks like NuGet packages caused the creation of a web.config in all module folders, and IIS or VS created a virtual directory on the DesktopModules folder. In addition, it also converted all of our module folders to Applications which had to be removed as well.