# Ajax Call can't find webmethod

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax, dotnetnuke

I have a dnn module and I am trying to make an ajax call in a page.
My client code is:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/DesktopModules/DMUI/Controls/Project/ProjectDrillingMapsView.ascx/GetMarkerList",
        dataType: "json"
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        var list = data;
        $.each(list, function (index, item) {
            alert(item);
     });
    })
    .fail(function (xhr, textstatus, errorthrown) {
     alert('Error:' + errorthrown + ', textstatus:' + textstatus);
    });
```

Server side I have this:

```
[WebMethod]
        public string GetMarkerList()
        {
            string output = null;
            List<Marker> markerList = new List<Marker>();
            //My main query where I get a list of Objects
            Expression<Func<DomainModel.Drilling, bool>> criteria = null;
            criteria = (d => d.ProjectId == this.SelectedProjectId && d.XCoordinate != 0 && d.YCoordinate != 0);
            _dpList = _drillingSrv.GetDrillingList(criteria, d => d.DrillingCode);

            foreach (DomainModel.Drilling dr in _dpList)
            {
                Marker marker = new Marker();
                marker.latitude = dr.GMapsLatitude.Value;
                marker.longitude = dr.GMapsLongitude.Value;
                marker.code = dr.DrillingCode;
                marker.depth = dr.Depth.Value;
                markerList.Add(marker);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            output = jss.Serialize(markerList);
            return output;
        }
```

At first I was getting an Internal Server Error 500.
Then I went into my web.config
and did this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2169847/1737287

Now I'm getting a Not Found Error 404.
I'm curious as to what I might be doing wrong...

Comment: You likely need to add the path to that Ajax Call into the URL handling rules for DNN to get it to ignore that URL and have it let .NET handle the request.

Comment: @ChrisHammond Can you link to some documentation about how to do that? I ended up doing a workaround for now. I did not use an ajax call at all. I created a hidden div with runat="server" and on prerender I called GetMarkerList to write the output into that div.
It gets me the same result and I "dodged" the ajax call issue. But i would still like to know whats wrong...

Answer (score 1):

"The 404 or Not Found error message is a HTTP standard response code indicating that the client was able to communicate with a given server, but the server could not find what was requested."

Provide full URL in ajax call.